# How to center text in footer (HTML) but have icons either left or right in the footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a mock up page for my assignment. and was wonder is it possible to have the text "copyright by jerry - 2017" centered  while having icons such as linked Facebook or Twitter off to the left or right of the text.

I'm relatively new and trying to understand the proper way of using html and CSS. so excuse the errors.

Comment: It's definitely possible - Flexbox might be your best bet as it will allow you to easily break your footer into thirds and insert different content in each section. I'd take a look at some tutorials for that and see how you get on.

Comment: It's even possible with just CSS. Please provide your code.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/eeVyOr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In future you need to add at least an example of what you did. You can use Javascript snippet in stackoverflow code editor or something like https://codepen.io/

Here is a small example of how you can center content with *CSS GRIDS*.

```css
footer {
  display: grid;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  grid: 50px / 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <a>Fb</a>
    <a>In</a>
    <a>Git</a>
  </div>
  <div>Just random Text</div>
  <div>
    <a>Twt</a>
    <a>Red</a>
    <a>Link</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Just press button *Run code snippet*

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `<center>...</center>` tags or include style="text-align:center" to whichever tag you use such as `<p style="text-align:center">...</p>`